# List of enums EF Core LINQ query

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

```
public enum GeneticModificationTypes
{
    SomeType = 1,
    AnotherType = 2,
    ThirdType = 3
}

public class GeneticModification: FullAuditedEntity<Guid>
{
   public ICollection<GeneticModificationTypes> Types { get; set; } 
}

modelBuilder.Entity<GeneticModification>()
        .Property(e => e.Types)
        .HasConversion(
            v => string.Join(',', v),
            v => v.Split(',', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToList() ?? new List<GeneticModiciation>())
        .Metadata.SetValueComparer(valueComparer);

var valueComparer = new ValueComparer<ICollection<string>>(
                    (c1, c2) => c1.SequenceEqual(c2),
                    c => c.Aggregate(0, (a, v) => HashCode.Combine(a, v.GetHashCode())),
                    c => (ICollection<string>)c.ToHashSet());
```

When I try to:

```
_context.GeneticModification.Where(r => r.GeneticModification.Any(b => listOfTypes.Contains(b)))
```

or

```
_context.GeneticModification.Where(r => r.GeneticModification.Contains(listOfTypes.Contains(b))
```

**edit**

it throws:

Message:

```
System.InvalidOperationException : The LINQ expression 'DbSet<GeneticModification>()
    .Where(m => m.OrganizationId == __organizationId_0)
    .OrderBy(m => m.CreationTime)
    .Skip(__p_1)
    .Take(__p_2)
    .Where(m => m.GeneticModificationTypes
        .Contains(__filters_GeneticModificationTypes_Value_3))' could not be translated. Additional information: Translation of method 'System.Linq.Enumerable.Contains' failed. If this method can be mapped to your custom function, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2132413 for more information. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.
```

What this model does is creating a Varchar column on the Table GeneticModification where the ICollection on my model gets translated to "Type1, Type2".

The table is the follow:
GeneticModification
Id   | Types
Guid | SomeType, AnotherType

Comment: I'm sure there's more detail to that exception; can you update your question to include all relevant information?

Comment: Is `GeneticModification` a table with only a single `int` or `tinyint` field whose values match the `GeneticModificationTypes` values? That's what this expression implies.

Comment: You can't force EF Core to support arrays when the underlying database doesn't support them. Even though you specified a *value* conversion, there's no code that tells EF Core how to construct valid SQL from operations on those "arrays". A string with commas isn't an array in any case

Comment: `creating a CSV column` there are no CSV columns. You may call strings with commas CSVs but that doesn't make them CSV files or arrays. Databases won't treat them as arrays

Comment: its a varchar column actually, the my model IColletion<EnumType> gets translated to a "type1,type2"

Comment: That's a bad design. EF Core is deprecated but even EF Core 7 doesn't support such things. EF Core 7 does support JSON columns which could hold arrays. Don't expect great performance if you try to filter by those values though

Comment: Some databases, eg PostgreSQL, have indexable array types. Only in these cases would you get proper filtering performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your database has a column with multiple numeric values concatenated into one string. This is VERY VERY bad if you want to filter or sort base don individual value within that column. It's messy and inefficient even in straight SQL, and Linq doesn't have any magic to generate that SQL.

Ideally I would use a related table instead of concatenated values in that column. If you can't change the database structure, then C# Has *better* ways of turning those strings into arrays, and can filter and sort from there, but you'll have to load mode data into memory that you otherwise would.

To do that, you'd build your base query, then insert `AsEnumerable()` to change from a SQL context to an in-memory context, then split the strings and do whatever filtering you need to from there.